# Group BY Expression column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

we're trying to make our table add together all values in column 2 (QtyComp - an expression column of **qtyorder * totalqty** basically), where they have the same ItemNo (column 1).

So, we currently get the below:

```
ItemNo          QtyCom
7441            3
7441            1
7441            5
```

What we want is it to return this:

```
ItemNo          QtyCom
7441            9
```

Our code is below; I've bolded the part that we need it to sum the results of:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
                         workorderdetails.qtycomplete * 
                         ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot AS QtyComp 
FROM   dbo.workorderdetails AS WorkOrderDetails 
       INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecfullstruc AS ItemSpecFullStruc_2 
               ON ItemSpecFullStruc_2.rootitemspecid = 
                  workorderdetails.itemspecid 
       INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecs AS ItemSpecs_2 
               ON ItemSpecs_2.itemspecid = ItemSpecFullStruc_2.childitemspecid 
       INNER JOIN dbo.workorder AS WorkOrder_1 
               ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = workorderdetails.workorderid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tobescheduled_completed 
                    ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = 
                       dbo.tobescheduled_completed.workorderid 
WHERE ( workorderdetails.completed = 1 ) 
      AND ( workorderdetails.compdate > Getdate() - 42 ) 
GROUP  BY ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
          workorderdetails.qtyordered, 
          ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot, 
          workorderdetails.[lineno], 
          workorderdetails.qtycomplete, 
          workorderdetails.compdate, 
          workorderdetails.qtycomplete * ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot
```

We would really appreciate some ideas!

Thanks, 
Trish

Comment: What do you mean by "it does the multiplication incorrectly"?

Comment: put some effort to make the code more readable.

Comment: Apologies. The key here is the 'Select' part of the equation, so (i've simplified the field descriptors):    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ItemSpecs.ItemNo, WorkOrder.QtyOrdered * ItemSpec.TotalQty AS QtyComp

Comment: The above returns the correct results on each line, but won't group them together. The alternate, which does group them, is SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ItemSpecs.ItemNo, SUM(WorkOrder.QtyOrdered * ItemSpec.TotalQty) AS QtyComp

Comment: By 'it does the multiplication incorrectly' I mean that while the second line above groups, it seems to Sum the QtyOrdered before doing QtyOrdered * TotalQty ?

Comment: You last query will sum and group it, there must be something wrong with data, can you add some sample data and expected output

Comment: Simplified the question now - hopefully that helps?

Comment: Looks like you need a SUM. Do a sum(workorderdetails.qtycomplete * 
                         ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot)

Comment: Also I believe you can remove the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
                     sum(workorderdetails.qtycomplete * 
                     ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot) AS QtyComp 
FROM   dbo.workorderdetails AS WorkOrderDetails 
   INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecfullstruc AS ItemSpecFullStruc_2 
           ON ItemSpecFullStruc_2.rootitemspecid = 
              workorderdetails.itemspecid 
   INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecs AS ItemSpecs_2 
           ON ItemSpecs_2.itemspecid = ItemSpecFullStruc_2.childitemspecid 
   INNER JOIN dbo.workorder AS WorkOrder_1 
           ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = workorderdetails.workorderid 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tobescheduled_completed 
                ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = 
                   dbo.tobescheduled_completed.workorderid 
WHERE ( workorderdetails.completed = 1 ) 
  AND ( workorderdetails.compdate > Getdate() - 42 ) 
GROUP  BY ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
      workorderdetails.qtyordered, 
      ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot, 
      workorderdetails.[lineno], 
      workorderdetails.qtycomplete, 
      workorderdetails.compdate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(QTYCOM) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMNO) 
FROM
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Once you will use `top` for `select` statement, you need to use order by. you can try the following query.

```
SELECT TOP(100) PERCENT A.itemno,SUM(QtyComp) FROM
(SELECT ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
                     (workorderdetails.qtycomplete * 
                     ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot) AS QtyComp 
FROM   dbo.workorderdetails AS WorkOrderDetails 
   INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecfullstruc AS ItemSpecFullStruc_2 
           ON ItemSpecFullStruc_2.rootitemspecid = 
              workorderdetails.itemspecid 
   INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecs AS ItemSpecs_2 
           ON ItemSpecs_2.itemspecid = ItemSpecFullStruc_2.childitemspecid 
   INNER JOIN dbo.workorder AS WorkOrder_1 
           ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = workorderdetails.workorderid 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tobescheduled_completed 
                ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = 
                   dbo.tobescheduled_completed.workorderid 
WHERE ( workorderdetails.completed = 1 ) 
  AND ( workorderdetails.compdate > Getdate() - 42 ) ) A
GROUP  BY A.itemno
ORDER BY A.itemno
```

Thanks